# How to prepare a code sample when working with a game engine?

Tags: interviewing, applications

I'm applying for a position of Unity3D programmer, and I'm asked to provide a code sample. Preparing a code sample for a "standalone" technology, like python or java or whatever is simple enough, but I don't know how to act when I'm dealing with a game engine. I fear that providing a, for example, controller class without the broader context will not satisfy the recruiters.

I've thought about three options here: either providing just one class with ~100 lines of code, which is what I would do if it was a python job, provide the top level model, view and controller classes, or give a full Unity3D project with scenes, textures, config files etc. I think the middle option is the best to go with, but I'm afraid that it's a bit too much and the recruiter would be happy with just a piece of the code, without the context. What should I send?

Comment: Have you tried asking the recruiter? The specific expectations will vary with potential employer.

Comment: @motosubatsu I was afraid that they'd think it's a stupid question and something that I should know myself. I'm probably way too stressed out about this application. But if you think it's ok to ask, I'll give it a try

Comment: I wouldn't class it as a stupid question, good luck!

Comment: Any answer here will be completely opinion based.  Your best bet for accuracy is to ask the recruiter as @motosubatsu pointed out.  VTC

Comment: is the title of the position really Unity3D programmer , or is something more like Game Developer, if it's the former, I'd think they're only interested in the code you can produce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody on the internet can provide the correct answer to this question. Only one person knows the answer - the hiring manager.

Ask the recruiter for more information about this code submission.